# At what point of the game should I request users leave a review?

Tags: mobile

I'm planning on displaying a dialog requesting users review my Android game, but I'm wondering at what point I should display the dialog. I wont show the dialog until the user has completed several levels, but I can't decide where in the game flow to place it.

I have several options.

1. On game launch - my concern with this is that they're looking to play a game at this moment in time, not review the game.
2. On game exit - this seems a fairly classic time to do it, but many users wont quit by pressing back, often they'll just use the home button, or just turn the phone off. Also, if a user is stopping playing then they'll often be doing so because they've got something else to do.
3. On level completion - I will only request the review on successful level completion as I assume a player will be feeling good about the game at that point in time. My concern with this is that it interrupts game flow.

I'd be interested in hearing the thoughts of others on this.

Comment: This is more of a discussion then anything, but if I were you I'd just have a small request at the start of the game. It's only there once, and is a pretty reasonable request especially if your game is free.

Comment: @Ben Design related questions are usually more of a discussion/opinion based as there's rarely a black and white answer. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 4):

Option 3 sounds like a good idea, but! Don't prompt the user in a way that they have to perform an action to get past the reviewing. I find this highly annoying. Instead, create a button somewhere in the score screen which they can click when they feel like it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've probably answered your own question. There are concerns with both options 1 and 3 as they  interrupt the flow of getting into the game and while playing. If I were to ask users to leave a review it would be on exit of the game. I have had apps ask me to review the application on first start-up without even using it in the first place. I found this to be fairly annoying as it should recognize that I haven't used the app. Reviewing during play is another one I've come across in games but the fact that it happened during play would actually affect the review of the game itself because it has just interrupted my enjoyment of an otherwise great game. With option 2, I understand your concern with users not pressing the back button and using home etc, but the fact that users are using the home/power button is indication of the fact that they're not in the mindset to review in the first place and will probably rush a review with a not so accurate evaluation. I know most of time I use the back button and when an app asks me to review, I usually provide honest feedback as I have had a chance to use the app and properly evaluate its features without interruption. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

What I've seen other popular games do is prompt you when you open the app, but only after you've played it once or twice. I'm guessing you could record the number of times the app has started, and then after they've opened it however many times, you can prompt them to review.